# How to load .dds files into a picturebox?

Tags: c#, image, directdraw, dds-format

How do I load .dds texture files as an Image in C#? There's nothing useful on google that I could find.

The more information with samples you give me,the better it will be for me to understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the short answer is that you don't. [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) says that the supported formats are BMP, GIF, EXIG, JPG, PNG and TIFF.

Update: there seem to be a number of [converters to be found through Google](http://www.google.se/search?q=dds+image+converter), that might help you out. Also, as Wayne suggests, look at XNA (if you didn't already). The [Texture2D.FromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb196945.aspx) method seems to handle the .dds files, but I never used it myself so I can't say if it is what you are looking for or not...

Comment: Well my question then turns into "How do I convert a .dds file into jpg/png/gif/tiff/bmp"

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. Here is a good solution.

1. Source: http://www.mastropaolo.com/devildotnet/
2. Download Version 1.3 from that link (bottom of page)
3. Add the Devil.NET.dll as a reference to your application
4. Use the code that I have supplied below.

   PictureBox1.Image = DevIL.DevIL.LoadBitmap(DDS_File_Path)

It's really that easy. We owe the DevIL .NET Wrapper creator a beer.

Comment: It's worth noting that his library doesn't parallelize well; using `Parallel.ForEach` gives various memory access exceptions and `null` return values for the `LoadBitmap` call. Still, this saves a lot of work...

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the Microsoft's [XNA Game Studio SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/xna/default.aspx) to load the textures in memory and possibly capture the images in a System.Drawing.Graphics usable way.