# Converting .dds to .png: is XNA really this convoluted?

Tags: c#, xna, png, image-conversion

I have a .dds file and I want a .png file. Although I already [found out about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865413/how-to-load-dds-files-into-a-picturebox/1580678#1580678) the [DevIL.NET library](http://www.mastropaolo.com/devildotnet/), the API design there of one static class does not parallelize, so I am hoping to find another method. This led me to XNA.

But, here's how far I got with that idea...

- OK, it looks like I want this `Texture2D` class; then I can call `myTexture2D.SaveAsPng`.
- But how do I get one of those from my .dds file? Well the documentation seems to indicate I want to use `myContentManager.Load<Texture2D>`.
- Oh crap, that wasn't it, that's some kind of game content management system. Well, my searching seems to have turned up a lot of uses of `myTexture2D.LoadFile`; I'll go for that.
- Uh am I missing an assembly reference or something? Oh no, I get it, they removed that method between 3.1 and 4.0, awesome. OK, well, it's a bit more annoying, but `myTexture2D.LoadStream` isn't really a problem.
- Wait what's this now? It wants a `GraphicsDevice`? Hmm it looks like one usually gets one of those via a `GraphicsDeviceManager`... oh wait, I'm not going down that path again, no more `Manager`s for me.
- I guess I'm supposed to instantiate this thing manually. OK well this isn't too hard... `var myGraphicsDevice = new GraphicsDevice(GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter, GraphicsProfile.HiDef,` (uh oh what is this `PresentationParameters` thing well OK I'll just try `new PresentationParameters());`.
- Well that threw an exception. They want... a `DeviceWindowHandle` in my `PresentationParameters`? **BUT I'M RUNNING A CONSOLE APP!!**

So I'm really hoping there's a less convoluted way of doing this; perhaps some kind of default `GraphicsDevice` I could use. It feels pretty silly to create a whole window just to convert .dds to .png.

Alternative suggestions for my conversion problem welcome, I guess, although it would probably be worthwhile to understand how to use XNA from non-XNA code in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a command line app that needs to create an XNA graphics device, the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863575/hlsl-enforce-constant-register-limit-at-compile-time/2873609#2873609) should be of some assistance.

In a nutshell, you need some of the classes from the [WinForms sample](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/sample/winforms_series1) to avoid having to mess around creating a graphics device services and so on (specifically the classes `ServiceContainer` and `GraphicsDeviceService`).

Then you can do this:

```
Form form = new Form(); // Dummy form for creating a graphics device
GraphicsDeviceService gds = GraphicsDeviceService.AddRef(form.Handle,
        form.ClientSize.Width, form.ClientSize.Height);

ServiceContainer services = new ServiceContainer();
services.AddService<IGraphicsDeviceService>(gds);
content = new ContentManager(services, "Content");
```

Tada - now you have a working `ContentManager` that you can use to load stuff. I believe you should be able to get the actual `GraphicsDevice` from the `GraphicsDeviceService`, too.

The form you create is never displayed. Remember to reference `System.Windows.Forms.dll` in your project.

Disclaimer: This was written for XNA 3.1. I haven't tested it in 4.0, but I suspect it will work with little or no modification.

Answer (score 3):

From the top of my head (haven't used XNA for a while):

- Conversion of datatypes is not a common scenario for XNA. It expects to get all assets preprocessed by the content pipeline.
- XNA expects the graphics device quite often, windowless applications are out of XNAs scope.

It seems to me that you are using the wrong tool for the job, although I couldn't tell another one except DevIL, which you already dismissed.