# how can i use content manager in console aplication to load a new Model?

Tags: c#, xna

how can i use content manager in console application to load a new Model?

I want to load mesh data without any display ?

Answer (score 3):

Check out my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849161/converting-dds-to-png-is-xna-really-this-convoluted). It contains code for getting a `ContentManager` working in a console application.

To duplicate it here briefly:

You need the `ServiceContainer` and `GraphicsDeviceService` classes from the [WinForms sample](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1). Then just use this code:

```
Form form = new Form(); // Dummy form for creating a graphics device
GraphicsDeviceService gds = GraphicsDeviceService.AddRef(form.Handle,
        form.ClientSize.Width, form.ClientSize.Height);

ServiceContainer services = new ServiceContainer();
services.AddService<IGraphicsDeviceService>(gds);
content = new ContentManager(services, "Content");
```

And, of course, include the necessary references (`System.Windows.Forms.dll`).